# >>> import pikle Traceback (most recent call last): File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: No module named 'pikle'

Tags: python-3.x

I can not import pikle.
and,I can not install pikle.
Collecting pikle
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pikle (from versions:
)
No matching distribution found for pikle
Why ??
My python version is 3.5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably trying to use to [Pickle](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html), which is spelled with a "ck", not just a "c". So, replacing "pikle" with "pickle" should resolve your problem.

Comment: No problem. Welcome to Stack Overflow! If this helped answer your question, you can mark the answer as accepted if you would like :)